# How to programmatically login using FORM authentication?

Tags: java, forms, authentication, servlets

I have a java web-app that uses form authentication to login and it has been working well.  However, I'd like to access some of the services of the web-app programmatically but I'd like to keep them behind the security constraints.

My thought was to make a call to 'j_security_check' and POST the 'j_username' and 'j_password' fields.  I figured this would establish the session so that future requests would be allowed. But whenever I make the request the authentication servlet returns a 408. I'm sure that cookies are enabled so I'm not sure what is going on.

Is there a documented way for programmatically connecting to a server that uses form authentication?

EDIT: I've come up with a way to do this.  You need to first make a call to a service and then save that session cookie that is created.  Then you can make a call to the 'j_security_check' and pass it your username and password, however, you need to make sure you set the referer (sic) as whatever your login page is.  Finally, you should be able to make the call to the service of interest.

This is quite a hack but seems to work reliably ... I wish there was a better way.

Comment: I don't think that error 408 has anything to do with cookies enabled: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408.html

Comment: alfasin: sorry, I didn't mean to imply they were related, only that cookies need to be enabled to even establish a connection (I had this problem earlier).

Comment: You'd need to show how exactly you're currently programmatically sending the HTTP request. You also need to prove/argument your statement *"I'm sure that cookies are enabled."* because the symptoms indicate that this is actually not true at all.

Comment: BalusC: Thanks for the response, but I didn't go into details about what I tried because I'm not confident it is even the right thing to do. I didn't want to influence the responses ... I'm generally asking if there is a way to programmatically log into a java web app that uses FORM authentication (i.e., uses the j_security_check service).